# Changing Stored Procedure Parameters in Excel/VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm successfully pulling data into excel via SQL queries formatted like so in VBA:

```
.Open "exec sp_MyProcedure @Node_Id = 05,@Subsidiary_Cd = '1',@WeekEndDate = '2016-05-28', @JobType = '12',@ReportLevel = 4"
```

I would like to either have the user enter the most current week ending date, which would change the @WeekEndDate parameter to their entry or have a cell displaying the most recent week end date without needing user entry (if that's possible?. All other parameters remain the same. I'm new to vba and don't have much experience in excel to any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
Dim NodeId, SubsidiaryCd, WeekEndDate, JobType, ReportLevel

NodeId = 05
SubsidiaryCd = "1"
WeekEndDate = "2016-05-28"
JobType = "12"
ReportLevel = 4

.Open "exec sp_MyProcedure " & _
    "@Node_Id = " & NodeId & "," & _
    "@Subsidiary_Cd = '" & SubsidiaryCd & "'," & _
    "@WeekEndDate = '" & WeekEndDate & "', " & _
    "@JobType = '" & JobType & "'," & _
    "@ReportLevel = " & ReportLevel
```

This is exactly the same as the previous instruction; you now just need to change the constant value for the `WeekEndDate` variable to the desired date, like:

```
WeekEndDate = Format(Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it depends on what you consider the last day of a given week.  For my test, I'm assuming Saturday.

Second, I'm assuming by "most current week", you mean the last FULL week (as in not the week we are currently in).

Third, I'm assuming the code snippet you included is the SQL you have integrated within your VBA code.

So, if you have `=TODAY()` in Cell A1, you can put the following formula in Cell A2, then change your VBA snippet to the following:

Formula: `=A1-WEEKDAY(A1)`

```
.Open "exec sp_MyProcedure @Node_Id = 05,@Subsidiary_Cd = '1',@WeekEndDate = '" & ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value & "', @JobType = '12',@ReportLevel = 4"
```

From here, you could follow the same idea to customize all parameters in your procedure.

Comment: You're assumptions are correct, however after changing my code I get "error converting data type varchar to smalldatetime." Smalldatetime is my data type in sql, any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You will need to add a time to your date field, either in Excel, or manually in the VBA.  Could probably just b e defaulted to midnight